# Airship push-worker.js send variables

Tags: javascript, urbanairship.com

I don't know if it is possible. I have the main page with JavaScript. I want to send the token, appkey and vapidPublicKey using variables to the push-worker.js of airship.

How can I send that variables? I am using .Net and I have the configuration in other pages and using razor I can assign the value to variables but push-worker looks like doesn't accept window object (I think reasons of security)

Do I have any other way to send variables to push-worker file? I am using all the navigators... then it is another problem.

Comment: Tip: on Stack Overflow, the generally accepted policy is to not add tags to titles, and for editors to remove them when they are seen. Meta question: [Why is removing tags from the title suggested so often?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253028/why-is-removing-tags-from-the-title-suggested-so-often)